# replace text conditionally using regex and index

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code where I'm getting rich text and want to replace things. Here I've 2 queries.

1. How can I match `*`, `**`, and `***` separately?
2. How can I conditionally replace data? i.e. if the index of `***` from match is 1 I want to have it replaced by `_*` else `*_`.

Here is my sample code.

```js
let x =
  "Lorem ***ipsum*** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Ratio quidem vestra sic cogit. *Qui\\-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus\\-dicitur oculis se privasse;* Sed in rebus apertissimis ***nimium longi sumus. Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re; **Que Manilium, ab iisque M.** Quis animo aequo videt eum, quem inpure ***ac flagitiose putet vivere? Duo Reges: constructio interrete.";

var re = new RegExp(/(\*)(\*)(\*)/g);
var results = new Array(); //this is the results you want
for (let match of x.matchAll(re)) {
  results.push(match.index);
}

results.forEach((item, idx) =>
  idx % 2 === 0
    ? (x = replaceRange(x, item, item + 3, "_*"))
    : (x = replaceRange(x, item, item + 3, "*_"))
);

function replaceRange(s, start, end, substitute) {
  return s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);
}
console.log(x);
```

When I run this code, it is not replacing the data as expected. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: and you don’t need to do anything with `**` and `*` ?
what if there is `****` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do either

Comment: @Shub `***` is the max cap.

Comment: @JBaczuk I'm trying to convert my input string into a markdown format for front end display.  and my use case is string surrounded by `***` should be bold italic, which in markdown would be of format `_* data *_`.

Comment: what markdown processor are you using? I thought *** is bold italic in markdown... https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#bold-and-italic

Comment: @JBaczuk Yes, you are right, but my output is for slack, where the bold italic is `_* data *_`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [RexExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), which is stateful and keeps track of the last match so you can iterate over each match. Then use a counter to keep track of how many matches you've found so you know whether to use `*_` or `_*`.

```
let x =
  "Lorem ***ipsum*** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Ratio quidem vestra sic cogit. *Qui\\-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus\\-dicitur oculis se privasse;* Sed in rebus apertissimis ***nimium longi sumus. Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re; **Que Manilium, ab iisque M.** Quis animo aequo videt eum, quem inpure ***ac flagitiose putet vivere? Duo Reges: constructio interrete.";

const regex = new RegExp(/\*\*\*/g)
let result
let matchCount = 0
while(result !== null)
  {
    result = regex.exec(x)
    if (result === null) break
    matchCount += 1
    matchCount % 2 === 0
      ? (x = replaceRange(x, result.index, result.index + 3, "_*"))
      : (x = replaceRange(x, result.index, result.index + 3, "*_"))
  }

console.log('x', x)

function replaceRange(s, start, end, substitute) {
  return s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the same `*` pattern after and before each word with *Backreference*, which matches the same text as matched by the 1st capturing group. For instance, with triple asterisks as in `***`, the regex could be:

```
[^_]([*]{3})(\w+)\1
```

Using this replacement:

```js
 _*$2*_
```

Explanation:

- `[^_]`: avoids capturing if it starts with `_`
- `([*]{3})`: capture group that matches exactly 3 `*
- `(\w+)`: capture group that matches any word character at least once.
- `\1`: backreference to the first capture group, it will capture its same match.

Regarding your queries, it depends on the replacements. Since the provided example  `_*` also has an asterisk, you must adapt the regex so that it won't substitute the output of the previous regex.

```js
let x =
  "Lorem ***ipsum*** dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quod non faceret, si in voluptate summum bonum poneret. Ratio quidem vestra sic cogit. *Qui\\-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus\\-dicitur oculis se privasse;* Sed in rebus apertissimis ***nimium longi sumus. Eiuro, inquit adridens, iniquum, hac quidem de re; **Que Manilium, ab iisque M.** Quis animo aequo videt eum, quem inpure ***ac flagitiose putet vivere? Duo Reges: constructio interrete.";

const re1 = new RegExp(/[^_]([*]{1})(\w+)\1/g);
const re2 = new RegExp(/([*]{2})(\w+)\1/g);
const re3 = new RegExp(/[^_]([*]{3})(\w+)\1/g);
 
let result = x.replaceAll(re3, " _*$2*_");

console.log(result);
```